# Directory Name is Invalid when navigating into .zip file

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I seem to be having trouble navigating into a .zip file via command line.

If I put the following statement into command line:

"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre6\core.zip"

and hit enter, cmd line will open up the zip folder which is great. But I then want to navigate to "bin" folder within the zip folder:

"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre6\core.zip\bin"

and for this line, command line throws an error and says that the directory name is invalid.

This doesnt make much sense to me considering the cmd line was able to navigate successfully into the .zip file.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Answer (score 1):

Zip file's content cannot be accessed automatically using Java. You should extract the desired content into a temporary folder in order to access it. But when you don't know the type of the item you are trying to extract (folder or file), it would be better to extract all the zip, test if the resource is a file or folder and do some treatment regading it.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the .zip file first before you navigate into it. Some things remain hidden until it is unzipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making by Java you can use `ZipEntry`.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/myZip.zip"); // use for get the zip

zipFile.entries(); // get the entries;
```

For more you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html).